# What is the preferred approach to do non-blocking select statement with channels in Go

Tags: go, channel

Here's an example with what I want to do

```
func (zoo *Zoo) feedAnimals(food Food) {
    for animal := range zoo.Animals {
        select {
        case animal.EatChan() <- food:
        default: // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Animal's `EatChan` has a small buffer, some times rate of which `feedAnimals` is called more often than the rate of which some animals can consume the food. When that happens, if I omit `default` statement in the `select` block, the select statement will block the `for loop` and other hungry animals can't get their food. So I'd rather skip the animal that is full (i.e. the channel has reached its capacity.)

However, having an empty `default` feels weird to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can increase the buffer size, which will only delay the problem, or add the default to skip the backed-up animal. The empty default case is fairly common for cases like this.

Comment: Yeah, it may feel weird, but that's the best way to do what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: @JimB is this a busy loop? Each loop iteration targets a different consumer.

Comment: @Adrian: you're right, for some reason I read hat as an empty for loop.

Comment: It's the right way to check if the channel is blocked and then move on if it is.

Comment: "having an empty default feels weird to me". Just get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, having an empty default feels weird to me.

It shouldn't.

> Is there a better way to do this?

No.

You're already doing it properly.  The empty default isn't a "do nothing" statement, it's a "don't block" statement. This is just the semantics of how a non-blocking select works.